# Split a JSON column into multiple columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table signal which has a JSON column called signal_range and I want to split the range into different columns in a SELECT query.

```
Brand                         signal_range 
 AB    {"Weak": {"low": 15, "high": 120}, "Strong": {"low": null, "high": -240}, "Average": {"low": -240, "high": 15}}
 CA      
 FZ    {"Weak": {"low": 10, "high": 100}, "Strong": {"low": null, "high": -200}, "Average": {"low": -200, "high": 10}}
```

Expected output

```
Brand    Weak_low   Weak_high  Strong_low Strong_high  Average_low  Average_high
 AB      15           120                    -240         -240        15
 CA     
 FZ      10           100                    -200         -200        10
```

Is there anyway we can get this output in a select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
 select brand, 
    signal_range#>'{Weak,low}' weak_low,signal_range#>'{Weak,high}' weak_high,
    signal_range#>'{Strong,low}' strong_low,signal_range#>'{Strong,high}' strong_high,
    signal_range#>'{Average,low}' average_low,signal_range#>'{Average,high}' average_high 
 from signal
```

Mind upper-/lowercase.  If you have uppercase in column names you need to adjust for that with "" around the names.  I really recommend all lowercase names.

Comment: Hi. It worked well. Thank you. I have another table with the same column but is in varchar datatype. I tried to cast string by "select  signal_range::jsonb#>'{Weak,low}'.." and I am getting  ERROR: type "jsonb#" does not exist. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Just add paranthesis like this: select (signal_range::jsonb)#>'{Weak,low}'